# Drop Down Not Showing Content When On Certain Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a drop down display my other div's when on value 2. Now my drop down is "Was there a Witness to the Incident?" then with two options "No" being value 1 and "Yes" being value 2. So if value 2 "Yes" is selected then two more questions are shown "Name of Witness" and "Contact Number of Witness". But I can't seem to work out why it's not working, can anyone work out why this is?

Thanks again,

Matt.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('p select[name=dd_1]').change(function(e) {
    if ($('p select[name=dd_1]').val() == '2') {
      $('#irMainWitness').show();
      $('#irQMainWitness').show();
      $('#irBottomWitness').show();
    } else {
      $('#irMainWitness').hide();
      $('#irQMainWitness').hide();
      $('#irBottomWitness').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropDown {
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#irMain {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#irQMain {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#irMainWitness {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
#irBottomWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="irMain">
  <p>Was there a Witness to the Incident?:</p>
</div>
<div id="irQMain">
  <select name="dd_1" class="dropDown">
    <option value="1">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Name of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_16" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Contact Number of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irBottomWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_17" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector's wrong; that `select` is inside a `div`, not a `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to ensure that your selector is correct, you can do this by explicitly wrapping your name value within your selector in quotes as well as not scoping it inside of a `<p>` tag (as there was not currently in one within your markup) :

```
$('select[name="dd_1"]').change(function(e) { ... });
```

Additionally, you should be able to dramatically simplify your existing code by using the `toggle()` function :

```
$(function() {
  $('select[name="dd_1"]').change(function(e) {
    $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == '2');
  });
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $('select[name="dd_1"]').change(function(e) {
    $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == '2');
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropDown {
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#irMain {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#irQMain {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#irMainWitness {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
#irBottomWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="irMain">
  <p>Was there a Witness to the Incident?:</p>
</div>
<div id="irQMain">
  <select name="dd_1" class="dropDown">
    <option value="1">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Name of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_16" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Contact Number of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irBottomWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_17" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for the select element is wrong .It should be

```
 $('#irQMain select[name=dd_1]')
```

since your select element is inside the div element with id irQMain

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('#irQMain select[name=dd_1]').change(function(e) {

    if ($('#irQMain select[name=dd_1]').val() == '2') {
      $('#irMainWitness').show();
      $('#irQMainWitness').show();
      $('#irBottomWitness').show();
    } else {
      $('#irMainWitness').hide();
      $('#irQMainWitness').hide();
      $('#irBottomWitness').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropDown {
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#irMain {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#irQMain {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#irMainWitness {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
#irBottomWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="irMain">
  <p>Was there a Witness to the Incident?:</p>
</div>
<div id="irQMain">
  <select name="dd_1" class="dropDown">
    <option value="1">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Name of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_16" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Contact Number of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irBottomWitness">
  <textarea name="tb_17" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```